# Adding a DataTable to an existing DataTable cells

Tags: c#, datatable

Having this snippet:

```
DataTable dt;

//...
//Fills dt with data (hidden)
//...

dt.Columns.Add("newCol");
DataTable dt2;

//...
//Fills dt2 with data (hidden)
//...

dt.Rows[0]["newCol"] = dt2;
System.Diagnostics.WriteLine(dtRows[0]["newCol"]);
```

It prints me empty, so aparently I am not being able to add a datatable to an existing datatable cell.
I have tried to print both datatable's contents, prior to the assign, and they correctly print out the data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes you are doing wrong you are adding datatable in a datatable row. This is insane

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? could u plz explain why you need this type of code?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the inner DataTable and use an two-dimentional array instead, which is simpler to handle. I did have to specifiy the type in order to be correctly passed, afterwards, to a Javascript function, as JSON (with a serialize function applied)

```
dt.Columns.Add("newCol", typeof(System.String[,]));
```